# App Service for Linux Docker containers logging

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps

I've deployed `asp.net core 2.0.` app to azure linux docker container and i'm trying to figure out best way to handle app logs.

I just can't get to some nice / best practice workflow.

Of course, there is Kudu service or FTP access to logs which both show docker logs but the question is how to nicely handle log levels?

As usual, i'd like to turn on `Warning` and above in production, but if a problem occur, i want to turn on `Trace` to see everything but without redeploy/restart/anything. Since we're in docker and without access to `appsettings.json` so `reloadOnChange` obviously won't work and i am not sure how to do it?

What is the best practice for this kind of situation?

Comment: Closed, as it has the potential to be a very useful resource if we don't close it quickly.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to highlight some of the best practices that you can use for logging (sorry for the long post):

We log useful information into the Docker log that can help you troubleshoot your site when it doesn't start or if it's restarting. We log a lot more than you might be used to seeing in a Docker log, and we will continue to work on making this logging more useful.
You can find the Docker log in the /LogFiles directory. You can access this via the Kudu (Advanced Tools) Bash console, by using an FTP client to access it, or by using our API to download the current logs. (See "You can discover and download the latest Docker logs using Kudu" in this post for info on that.) The naming convention for the Docker log is YYYY_MM_DD_RDxxxxxxxxxxxx_docker.log.

Note that if you try and download the Docker log that is currently in use using an FTP client, you may get an error because of a file lock. In that case, you can download it using our API (see "You can discover and download the latest Docker logs using Kudu" in this post) or you can use "tail" in the console to view it. (Our API gets you the current Docker log, so if you want to review a past log, use the "tail" option.)
To view the Docker log using tail, access the console, switch into the LogFiles directory, and run this command:
tail 2017_09_05_RD*0FA_docker.log

“You can discover and download the latest Docker logs using Kudu”.

We have an API that allows you to easily see the current Docker log details (such as the filename, etc.) and also download the current Docker logs in Zip format.
To see details on the current Docker logs in JSON format, you can use this URL:
https://[sitename].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logs/docker
You can get to this easily by going to Advanced Tools (Kudu) and then appending "/api/logs/docker" to the URL. The output of this will be a JSON response with the most relevant and current Docker logs.
If you want to download the logs shown in the above API in Zip format, append "zip" to the URL. For example:
https://[sitename].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logs/docker/zip
You can also click the link in Advanced Tools (Kudu) to download your latest Docker logs in Zip format.

Azure App Service has a rich feature-set, but not all of those features are currently available for Linux apps. We're working on adding new features all the time, and once new features are added, they'll be enabled on the menu in the Azure portal. If the menu item for a particular feature is disabled (grayed out) in the menu for your Linux apps, it's simply because we haven't added that feature yet.

Reference: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/